# c++ zipping two vectors into a tuple

Tags: c++, stdvector

Coming from a syntactically simpler, dynamically typed language with a lot more built in functions (you know the one), I wanted to teach myself C++.
So I wanted to try recreating the zip(a,b) function. The idea is to take two list-like objects, and return a list of pairs from those two objects. E.g. zip({1,2,3},{a,b,c}) should return {{a,1}, {b,2}, {c,3}}.

Now I gather that the way to make such objects in C++ is with vectors, rather than arrays?
Below is my attempt to code the function, and a test to print its contents, but I get no actual output in the console. I even tried two different methods for printing the vector, so I suppose my zip() function messed up.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> zip(std::vector<float> a, std::vector<float> b)
{
    //Returns a vector of size 2 vectors for tuples of <a_i, b_i>
    //if the vectors are not of equal size, truncates to shortest.
    int len_a = a.size();
    int len_b = b.size();
    int size;
    if (len_a<len_b)
    {
        size=len_a;
    }
    else
    {
        size=len_b;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> c;
    for (int i; i<=size; i++)
    {
        //c[i] = {a[i],b[i]}; commented out. I think the below is more correct?
        c.push_back( {a[i] , b[i]} );
    }
    return c;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<float> sample_a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<float> sample_b= {7,7,7};

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> output_c;
    output_c = zip(sample_a,sample_b);

//First attempted method for print
    for (std::vector<float> a: output_c)
    {
        for (float b: a)
        {
            std::cout << b << std::endl;
        }
    }
//Second attempted method for print
    for (int i=0; i<=output_c.size();i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=output_c[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << output_c[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still very new to the use of C++, and my 'learning' strategy has been to write smallish programs for things I found useful. Any general tips on improving the above also much appreciated!

Comment: don't ignore warnings https://godbolt.org/z/9jcxf7ccG

Comment: and all loops have the bounds wrong. `for (int i; i<=size; i++)`  -> `for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)`

Comment: We have had `std::pair` for quite a while now.

Comment: Any learning strategy should start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: after fixing the typos the code works as expected https://godbolt.org/z/b593eMnn6.

Comment: Ah, thank you all for helping point out the mistakes. Although I did in fact not get any error messages. There was simply no output when running my zip.exe. Can be marked as answered! And thanks for the useful links.